# How to fix 'in bash after checking with if condition else statements also getting executed'?

Tags: python, bash, io, automation

I am taking URLs from a file, for them to use curl to download images, after making a change in the URL `URL=${URL%$'\r'}`, I am running loop to read every line, taking input in variable and classifying the images by TensorFlow, if they are infographics then it should execute the if statement, else it should execute else statement.
On executing the bash script both the if and else statements are getting executed

in the else statement getting executed, on printing `echo ${var%$'something'}` it does not print anything...
also, the script is running fine when taking input from the keyboard.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r file
do
  url=${file%$'\r'}
  var=`python test_python_classify.py $url`
  if [ $var == 1 ]
  then
    echo $var
    curl -o image.png $url
    python description1.py $url
  else
    echo "\n\n\n"
    echo ${var%$'yoyo'}
    echo "lol"
  fi
done < url.txt
```

Edit: the loop is getting executed two times. Is it caused by the changing the string or what, please help.

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_python_classify.py", line 3, in <module>
    URL = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
./pipeline1.sh: line 8: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

Comment: that sounds like a job for full python & dropping bash.

Comment: how can you say so?

Comment: I mean: you already use python inside your script, which only does loops, file reads & prints. Using python _everywhere_ may solve your issue. Bash is full of traps. Python isn't (and fails with clean exceptions when you have an error). Just a piece of advice from someone who gave up bash completely for python.

Comment: we may need to see your python script to understand what they print and what they're returning

Comment: this is the error i am getting, the python file takes an url of an image  as argument and returns 1 if the image is an infographics

Comment: you're mixing return code and return output in your script.

Comment: sorry, python script is printing 1 if it is an infographics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors.

First `$url` is empty (empty line in your script, maybe), which makes python fail when trying to access the argument. That's the meaning of this error:

```
URL = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Then you're mixing *return code* and *return value* in your script:

```
var=`python test_python_classify.py $url`
if [ $var == 1 ]
  then
```

the python script *exits* with a 1 return code, it doesn't *print* 1. In fact, your script prints nothing (crashes traces go to `stderr`), so `$var` is empty and you get a shell syntax error because you didn't protect the variable with quotes.

```
./pipeline1.sh: line 8: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

If you need to test the return code, with `$?` also filter empty urls (my bash is rusty but that should work):

```
if [ ! -z "$url" ]
then
   python test_python_classify.py $url
   if [ $? == 1 ]
   then
```

If the python script *prints* a value, first test return code to see if it succeeded, then check the printed value

```
if [ ! -z "$url" ]
then
   var = $(python test_python_classify.py $url)
   # check if returncode is 0, else there was an error
   if [ $? == 0 ]
   then
      # protecting return with quotes doesn't hurt
      if [ "$var" == 1 ]
      then
```

As suggested in comments, this could use a major full python rewrite, which would simplify all those bash/python interface issues. Something (untested) like:

```
import sys,subprocess  # we could use python script functions too
with open("url.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
     url = line.rstrip()
     if url:
         output = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable,"test_python_classify.py",url])
         output = output.decode().strip()  # decode & get rid of linefeeds
         if output == "1":
            print("okay")
            subprocess.check_call(["curl","-o","image.png",url])
            subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,"description1.py",url])
         else:
            print("failed: {}: {}".format(url,output))
```

Comment: thanks but i had mistakenly put some new lines in url files, that caused that error, thank you for your time, this place is amazing